# Get number of partitions in AWS Glue for specific range

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue

I want to list all the partitions for a given table and get a count of it, but
`aws glue get-partitions --database-name ...` returns detailed information about each partitions which is not very helpful in this case.

Let's say my table is partitioned by `input_data_date` and `country` I want to know how many partitions I have for a given day.

I can do something with this

```
aws glue get-partitions --database-name MYDB --table-name MYTABLE --expression "input_data_date = '2021-07-09' "
```

But it needs some scripting I was looking for a better and cleaner way just by AWS CLI or ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS CLI uses JMESPATH, which has a [`length()`](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#length) function. Therefore, you can use:

```
aws glue get-partitions --database-name xx --table-name xx --query 'length(Partitions[])'
```

That will return the total number of partitions.

If you want to do something more specific ("how many partitions I have for a given day"), you'd probably need to use a better SDK (eg Python with boto3) to process the information.